# Connect to remote mySQL server Delphi XE5 on Android

Tags: android, mysql, delphi

I'm pretty new to mySQL and Android development. I'm using Embarcadero Delphi XE5 to create an Android application. I have set up a remote mySQL server online. I want the Android app to connect to the remote mySQL server and display information from a row located in the table in something like a label when the program starts. I have read that android cannot directly connect to mySQL, so how should I go  about doing this? Since I'm new to mySQL, can anyone help me to accomplish this?

Comment: It's almost never a good idea to open your database on the server. The typical way of doing this is to write a server-side script or application that your Android app can then ask (via a normal web request - HTTP, for instance) for the data you need for your app. Exposing your actual database is a major security hole, especially if you keep any sensitive/personal information in it.

Comment: I'm hosting the mysql server on a free hosting site just to test the app first.. So I don't think I will be able to write the server side script(or am I wrong?) . Even if I could, I don't know any other coding language besides delphi and some sql.

Comment: Delphi is perfectly capable of creating CGI and WinCGI applications, and using Indy, ICS, or another of the internet component sets available allows you to write a full server (HTTP or FTP, for instance). I can't answer your "(or am I wrong?)" question, because I don't know anything about your hosting site (nor do I need to); you'd have to check with that hosting site to see what's possible and what isn't.

Answer (score 1):

To develop Android applications that work directly with MySQL server, you can use MyDAC ( http://www.devart.com/mydac ).
MyDAC works with MySQL directly without the use of the client library. Such approach has the following advantages:

- there is no need of libmysql.dll, which means less problems with deploying applications;
- performance is better;
- possibility to develop mobile (Android and iOS) applications.

For more information, please refer to the following articles:
http://blogs.devart.com/dac/index.php/android-database-application-development-in-rad-studio-xe5.html
http://blogs.devart.com/dac/index.php/how-to-develop-ios-applications-in-delphi-xe4-using-devart-data-access-components.html

Comment: Both footer links are dead now